# $G$ is a non-abelian group of order 6 $ \implies G \approx S_3 $. Simpler proof?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups, group-isomorphism

I've seen some proofs of this fact but they seemed more complicated than necessary, so I've tried to come up with my own, which is hopefully simpler. **Can you kindly tell me if it's correct?**

**Proof.** $G$ cannot have an element of order 6, else it would be cyclic and thus abelian. So the elements of $G$ different from $e$ can only have order 3 or 2. If all $g \in G$ have order 2 then $G$ is abelian, so there must be at least one element $a \in G$ of order 3. The subgroup $H= \langle a \rangle$ is normal in $G$ because its index is 2. $G/H$ is a cyclic group of order 2. Let $b \not \in H$. We have $(bH)^2=H \implies b^2 \in H$. If $o(b)=3$, then $ b=b^4=b^2b^2 \in H$, a contradiction. So we must conclude that every $g \in bH$ has order 2.

We have $G= H \cup bH = \{e, a, a^2, b, ba, ba^2 \}$.  Moreover, $ab \in Hb = bH$ so $(ab)^2=e$. Then $ab=b^{-1}a^{-1}=ba^2$, which is exactly the relation in $S_3$. $\square$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Depending on what you assume, I don't think it can get any simpler than this. It's a little easier with Cauchy's theorem, which is what I used when I was assigned this as homework. Is that tool available to you?

Comment: @MattSamuel Not yet, I'm afraid. Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: Just to note: I second stanley dodds's remark that "simple" is subjective to what you already know. E.g. from my perspective, the simplest proof goes like this: there are only 2 groups of order 6, namely $C_6$ and $S_3$, the first one being abelian. Aside from that, +1 for your effort.

Comment: @lisyarus Absolutely. I meant that I find it simpler than the other proofs which assume the same background knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like this is indeed correct, but "simple" is somewhat relative; the simplicity of the proof really just depends on how many other facts or theorems you are allowed to use in it. Another example of a "simple" proof (quite similar to yours) might be:

$G$ has an order $2$ element $s$ and an order $3$ element $r$ by Cauchy's theorem (overkill, but saves writing). Now $2\nmid3$ so $s\notin\langle r\rangle$ so all elements of $\langle r\rangle,s\langle r\rangle$ are distinct, hence are the elements of $G$. Then consider $rs$; $s\notin\langle r\rangle\implies rs\notin\langle r\rangle$, and also $rs\ne s$. If $rs=sr$ then $G$ is abelian. The only element left is $rs=sr^2$, and we are done.

Comment: I haven't studied Cauchy's theorem yet but the proof is clear. May I ask though, how do you prove that $rs=sr \implies G$ is abelian? I can prove it, but my proof seems quite long.

Comment: @TheFootprint I have represented all the elements of $G$ in terms of $r$ and $s$, so in any product, you can just commute the $r$'s and $s$'s to swap the 2 elements round. Therefore any 2 elements commute, i.e. $G$ is abelian